# How to use $map with find in mongoose

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

I have a collection name event with following fields in a doc something like this

```
    {
_id:5d712ff47a545e067f0ab152
        eventid:"10nm",
        name:"Meeting With XC",
        status:"Open",
        plans:[{
        _id:5d712ff47a545e067f0ab153
        dataid:1yu7
        }]
    }
```

Plans array has only one field
I want to get the query output something like this

```
{_id:5d712ff47a545e067f0ab152
eventid:"10nm",
name:"Meeting With XC",
status:"Open",
planid:1yu7,
}
```

This is what I am trying with mongoose

```
let events=await Event.find({"status":"Open"},{"eventid":1,"name":1,"planid":1},{"planid":{"$map": { "input": "$plans", "as": "ar", "in": "$$ar.dataid" }}});
```

but its only returning the fields name and eventid .How to get this output?.Thanks For your help.

Comment: Look like you need to use aggregation because `$map` is aggregation pipeline operator.

Comment: aggregation with condition just like find?

Comment: Yes. Or you can map the result after find using javascript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use below aggregation

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  { "$match": { "status": "Open" }},
  { "$addFields": {
    "planId": {
      "$arrayElemAt": ["$plans.dataid", 0]
    }
  }},
  { "$project": { "plans": 0 }}
])
```

Comment: But i need a condition with find too? should i keep it with $match?

Comment: @trinity Updateed